# Angularjs getting started

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fresh to Angularjs and i wanted to learn from couple of Youtube tutorials, and i think i am getting a hold of it so i wanted to try out my first simpliest code, which looks like this.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <title></title>

</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="FCon">
    <span>A random value: </span><br><br>
    {{wrt1}}
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my script.js file(same folder as html file):

```
var app = angular.module('app' , []);

app.controler('FCon',function($scope) {
    $scope.wrt1 = Math.floor(Math.Random()*10+1);
});
```

I linked up the latest version of the framework but yet the browser(chrome) won't interpret the so called "expression" of wrt1 and it just stays there as a normal text.

Where did i do wrong? Guide me my brothers!

Comment: Which version of angular you are using ? Your code is a angular 2's code.

Comment: @SachinShah this code is certainly AngularJS code, not angular >= 2.

Comment: You can use chrome dev tools to debug your application. It will show you errors/warnings which will be very helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 2 typo's in your code

- `controller` instead of `controler`
- `random` instead of `Ramdom`

```js
var app = angular.module('app' , []);

app.controller('FCon',function($scope) {
    $scope.wrt1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div  ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="FCon">
      <span>A random value: </span><br><br>
      {{wrt1}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Quentin - I agree with your opinion. However, I considered this as an exception as OP is fairly new to the community and can have an experience of a working example here and could relate better.

Comment: Thank you good sir! I shall be more careful about the typos from now on

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal — So make a comment and link to JS Bin. Don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @KingYaroglek - Glad to help you!

Comment: @Quentin - Well I see a difference in conclusions here. The best I can do here is to vote to close.